# ADO - How to duplicate a record in table

Tags: sql, vb6

I'm creating copying TableiN into TableOut

```
cn.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO TableOut" & _
    "SELECT FirstName, Status " & _
    "FROM TableiN"
```

If Status is equal to "a+b" in a TableiN record,  I need that record to be copied twice in TableOut: one record with Status="a" and one record with Status="b"

Comment: What is your underlying database?  Sql Server, Oracle, Access, etc.?

Comment: Someone's stuck with a poorly-normalized table :( But it sounds like you're taking appropriate steps to fix the problem and replace the bad table.

Comment: Can there be more values? ie: `a+b+c` etc? If so, what's your worst case?

Comment: It's an Acess table. The only possible values in TableIn for Status are "a","b","a+b"

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS JOIN` to duplicate the records. `UNION ALL` can be used to specify the two statuses.

```
cn.Execute _
    "INSERT INTO TableOut" & _
    "SELECT FirstName, Status " & _
    "FROM TableiN CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'a' as status UNION ALL SELECT 'b' as status) as status_tb"
```